# Azure DevOps YAML: Conditional template call

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to check if Fetch_Commits succeeded in order to run jobs in `microservice-calls.yaml` file.
I don't want to use Stages since there are no semantic for separating among jobs.

Are there any similar syntax to

```
- ${{ if succeeded('Fetch_Commits') }}:
     - template: templates/microservices-calls.yaml
```

The YAML file:

```
trigger:
- trigger-branch

jobs:
    - job: Fetch_Commits
      displayName: Checkout
      pool:
       name: MyPool
      steps:
      - checkout: self
        fetchDepth: 2
    - ${{ if succeeded('Fetch_Commits') }}:
      - template: templates/microservices-calls.yaml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure Pipelines, `dependsOn` and `condition` cannot be used directly in template references. So, these properties need to be set on every job inside the template. If your `templates/microservices-calls.yaml` file contains multiple jobs, you need to set `dependsOn` and `condition` separately in each job. Assume your `microservices-calls.yaml` is as follows:

```
#  templates/microservices-calls.yaml
jobs:
- job: Microservice_Job_1
  dependsOn: Fetch_Commits
  condition: succeeded('Fetch_Commits')
  steps:
  - script: echo Running Microservice Job 1

- job: Microservice_Job_2
  dependsOn: Fetch_Commits
  condition: succeeded('Fetch_Commits')
  steps:
  - script: echo Running Microservice Job 2
```

Then you can use the template as the following yaml. `Microservice_Job` will only run when the `Fetch_Commits` job succeeds.

```
trigger:
- trigger-branch

jobs:
  - job: Fetch_Commits
    displayName: Checkout
    pool:
      name: MyPool
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 2

  - template: templates/microservices-calls.yaml
```

Comment: file `templates/microservices-calls.yaml` have other job templates call for each microservice I have. So I got errors using your approach, which I guess because adding jobs within another job as a step isn't possible. is it?

Comment: Hi  @MuhannadBashar, thanks for the explanation.  Yes, you are right. I thought it was a task in the template.  I have updated the answer.  Please check.